# Joomla Login Page Error

Tags: authentication, joomla

I am using the Joomla 1.5, During wrong  login `ID` and `Password`, its takes me other page with error like `Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.`

Need to show this `error` on same `login` page, how does it could be shown, i have tried the things but did not get so much help, Help me.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to ftp /components/com_users/controllers/user.php

search the code:-

```
// Login failed !
$data['remember'] = (int)$options['remember'];
$app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', $data);
$app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));
```

replace :-

```
$app->redirect(JRoute::_('your getting current url', false));
```